# how to get all inputs in one line?

Tags: python

I write this code but I want to take the input in one line. I tried using   map(int, input().split()) but I want to get in in a range of (m+1) and don't know how to add that

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import poly1d

m = int(input())
n = int(input())
y = []

if n >= 1 and m <= 20:
    for j in range(m + 1):
        c = int(input())
        y.append(c)

p1: poly1d = np.poly1d(y)


p2 = p1 ** n
o = p2.coef
print(*o, sep=" ")
```

Comment: "Get the input in one line", like this? [sample](https://repl.it/repls/HoarsePurpleAddin)

Comment: yes, I did that but I want to get the inputs in the range of m +1, like if m = 3 the user only can enter 3 numbers for c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user to input the x numbers (x = m) in oneline, you can use this:

```
your_input = input("enter the numbers with space in between:")
m, n = your_input.split()
print(f'first element is {m} and second is {n}')

c='0'
while len(c.split()) < int(m)+1 or len(c.split()) > int(m)+1: 
  c=input(f'Please enter {int(m)+1} numbers divided by space:')

y = c.split()

print(y)
```

Edited per comments.

Comment: thank you. but I don't want to give an error, like the for loop, I want the program only get m+1 number for the c.

Comment: Even if the user types 4 number(1,2,3,4) you want c to get (1,2,3)?

Comment: well you could do slicing on the list that you created so that y will hold only the elements you want..

Comment: No, m+1 is the range. so if the user enters m = 5 it will get 6 numbers. if m = 7 , user can enter 8 numbers.

Comment: I want the user to have limits for the input.

Comment: edited the answer. Used m=length of c as this was your comment to your question. (check above)